# Proving that $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{1+z}$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{1+z}$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

That's equivalent to prove that $f(1/z)=\frac{z \sin (1/z)}{1+z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

I considered the Laurent series around $0$:

$$z\sin (1/z)= z\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!z^{2n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!z^{2n}}$$
and the geometric series for $|z|<1$:
$$\frac{1}{1+z}=\frac{1}{1-(-z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n z^n.$$
Then
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n z^n \cdot  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!z^{2n}}.$$
Now I wonder if it's valid to use the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Products_of_finitely_many_infinite_series) rule to multiply these two series. Or if there's another way to solve this problem.

Comment: $\sin z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ (why? - what are entire functions with poles at infinity?); this means that for every $n$ there is $z_{m,n} \to \infty, \frac{ \sin z_{m,n}}{z_{m,n}^n} \to \infty, m \to \infty$; this clearly implies $\frac{ \sin z_{m,n}}{(1+z_{n,m})z_{m,n}^{n-1}} \to \infty, m \to \infty$, so $f$ has an essential singularity too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has zeroes at $\pi n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $f(1/z)$ has zeroes at ${1 \over \pi n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This couldn't happen if $z = 0$ were a pole of $f(1/z)$ since $|f(1/z)|$ would go to infinity as $z$ approaches zero.

If $z = 0$ were removable for $f(1/z)$, then the sequence of zeroes tending to zero would imply that $f(1/z)$ is identically zero on a neighborhood of the origin, which clearly isn't the case.

Thus the only remaining option is an essential singularity.

Comment: How can I compute $\lim_{z \to 0} |f(1/z)|$?

Comment: Once you prove that $z_0=0$ is essential for $z\mapsto f(1/z)$, you automatically know that $\lim_{z\to0}f(1/z)$ doesn't exist. It's one of the characterizations of the essential singularities.

Comment: But in the answer the limit $\lim_{z \to 0} |f(1/z)|$ was used to prove that $z=0$ is not a pole, before proving $f(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: The statement used is "$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} |f(1/z)| = \infty$ is false", for which you don't need that it's an essential singularity.

Comment: But why is $\lim_{z \to 0} |f(1/z)|=\infty$ false?

Comment: Because it has a sequence of zeroes approaching $z = 0$.

Comment: @Zarrax And $f(1/z)$ would be indetically zero on a neigborhood of the origin after removing the singularity? Is that because of the identity theorem? Is the biggest such neighborhood the unit disk? (since the other singularity is $−1$).

Answer (score 0):

Call $g(z)=z\sin(1/z)$ and notice that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{g(z)}{1+z}=\lim_{z\to0}g(z)
$$
but this last one doesn't exist since by the expansion you wrote for $g$, we have that $z_0=0$ is essential singularity for $g$.

So neither
$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{g(z)}{1+z}$ can exist, which is equivalent to say that $z_0$ is essential for such a function too.